Gitlab CI apparently missing needed compiler
I have used gitlab for quite a while now, but am trying to make use of its CI capabilities for the first time.  My yml file is failing.  The relevant portions are:
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  image: gcc:latest
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - mpif90 -c dt_data_mod.F90
    - echo "Compile complete."

The build fails with the error "/usr/bin/bash: line 159: mpif90: command not found".  Is this something I can take care of on my end somehow?  Or is it something I need to talk to the admins about?  Or am I trying to do something that can't be done?  What I really want to eventually do is get to the point where I can do a make command with a Makefile.  But it doesn't recognize "make" either.  Can that be done?

It does seem that the gcc image doesn't have mpif90 installed and neither make. I'm not familiar with that compiler but with that image I'd expect someone to run gcc main.c instead. So I'd suggest looking at the Docker image and making sure it does allow you to run mpif90, otherwise it is perhaps better to use a base ubuntu and install all the dependencies you need (or even creating a custom Docker image that you can pass to your job). Hope it helps!

@bhito  OK.  Thanks!
